# timing of multiple function calls

Tags: c++, timing

Coming from python I am trying to find a way to time several function calls in a c++ code. So far I am using this.

```
 void my_func(/*some args*/) {
   clock_t t_begin = std::clock();
   // code
   clock_t t_end = std::clock();
   double elapsed_secs_U = double(t_end - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 }
```

But this is highly repetitive. And I would like to have something like a function wrapper so that I can write:

```
 void timer(func, *args) {
   clock_t t_begin = std::clock();
   func(*args)
   clock_t t_end = std::clock();
   double elapsed_secs_U = double(t_end - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 }
```

which could be used like:

```
 timer(compute_a, a, b)
 timer(compute_b, b, c)
```

Is there any way to achieve this in C++?

PS: I need the timings in productive runs, thus I dont want to recompile my code with profiling flags and stick it into Valgrind or any other tool

Comment: I guess you could make some [variadic template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) doing that, if using [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11). Or simply a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using variadic template, you may do something like:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void timer(F f, Ts&&...args) {
   clock_t t_begin = std::clock();
   f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
   clock_t t_end = std::clock();
   double elapsed_secs_U = double(t_end - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

But simply

```
template <typename F>
void timer(F f) {
   clock_t t_begin = std::clock();
   f();
   clock_t t_end = std::clock();
   double elapsed_secs_U = double(t_end - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

should do the job, and pass capturing lambda when you need to pass argument:

```
timer([&](){ compute_b(b, c);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this pattern in the past. This captures the total time spent in a function for the entire life of the program, not the time spent in one call.

```
struct FunctionTimer
{
    FunctionTimer(std::string const& fname) : fname_(fname), totalTime_(0) {}

    ~FunctionTimer()
    {
       std::cout << "Total time in " << fname_ << ": " << totalTime_ << std::endl;
    }

    std::string fname_;
    double totalTime_;
};

struct TimeAccumulator
{
    TimeAccumulator(FunctionTimer& timer) : timer_(timer), begin_(std::clock()) {}
    ~TimeAccumulator()
    {
       clock_t end = std::clock();
       double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin_) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
       timer_.totalTime_ += elapsed_secs;
    }

    clock_t begin_;
    FunctionTimer& timer_;
};

void my_func(/*some args*/)
{
   static FunctionTimer timer("my_func");
   TimeAccumulator acc(timer);

   // code
}
```

If you would like to create a wrapper function for timing purposes and leave the rest of the functions untouched, some template magic *might* do the trick. I have to think about the details of how such a function template can be implemented.

Comment: But still I would need to modify all of my funcs instead of just calling them via `timer(my_func)` ?

Comment: @greole, that's the method I have used in the past. I wrapped the two lines of code in a macro to enable/disable them at compile time per compilation unit.