# What's the best c functions to compute the execution time of a program

Tags: c, function, time, timer

I want to get the execution time of a program that I build and specifically the the time needed to load the data, the execution, for some operations etc.  and of course the total any example code or direction where to see. I found something related for research purpose that the programer use MACROS before the and after like `#define COUNT__TIME_BEGIN` `#define COUNT__TIME_END` and in the MACROS declaration use `gettimeofday();` function is this right?

Comment: `gettimeofday` produces microsecond resolution. It's what I _used_ to use. Nowadays, I use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)`. It gives nanosecond resolution. Under linux [at least], it's low overhead because it's a `vdso` [fast] syscall. Or, with extra effort, on `x86`, you could use `rdtsc` but you have to determine the CPU frequency [to convert ticks to seconds] and that can be problematic.

Comment: For windows I used `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: so I need to multiply by  1000000 right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136319/timing-of-multiple-function-calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure a time interval in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150291/how-do-i-measure-a-time-interval-in-c)